# Extract html tag from content:encoded in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, rss, feed, src, yahoo-pipes

This is my pipes: [link](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=7068bab157d56b673c85799dd4ce56b6)

I need to get src attribute of the img tag that are inside the content:encoded

This is the content:encoded of the feed:

```
<p style="text-align:justify;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-49549" src="http://i2.wp.com/heshootshescoores.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/nhl.jpg?resize=600%2C400" alt="nhl"/></p>
<p style="text-align:justify;">...etc.
```

So in this example I would like to extract this link: ttp://i2.wp.com/heshootshescoores.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/nhl.jpg?resize=600%2C400

And export this attribute to a new item.media:thumbnail like this

```
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" 
url="HERE GOES THE SRC ATTRIBUTE.png"/>
```

Is it possible to do with Yahoo! Pipes?( I was thinking about regex but I am not familiar and I don't even know where to start.)

Thank You

---

FU question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605740/add-items-attribute-in-yahoo-pipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   (.*?)(?=src=)src=\"(.*?)\"(.*)
```

This will work.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bJ6rZ5/3

Comment: Since now I have a new question,I'll create a new separated question. Thanks